# Hover over button while still having hover effect of element behind it

Tags: css

I have created an element where when you hover within the area of the element a hover effect is applied (change background colour), on top of this element is a button.
When I hover over the button it causing the other hover effect to disappear, I want to be able to keep the hover for the whole time that the mouse is within the area of the first element.

[Example Code Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lwh8yt)

So when I hover over the button in the example, I still want the background of the `a` tag to be black. At the moment when I hover over the button it causes the black background to disappear. I also still want to be able to click on the button.

To achieve what I want to achieve would I need to use js? Or can it be done in CSS?

Comment: It seems like you don't need button here or <a> it is controversial as for me.

`<a id="label">
<span>Hidden Until Hover</span>
<span id="button1">Test Button</span>
</a>`

Using this structure you can control elements inside <a> and style it as you want.

If you need to do it in the structure you've provided, you can use css ~ or + selector. 
For example: `a:hover + button {color: red}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#button1 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 10%;
  left: 15%;
}
#label {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -10;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
#label span {
  color: white;
}
#label:hover {
  background-color: black;
}

#label button:hover{
  color:white;
```

```html
<a id="label"><span>Hidden Until Hover</span>
<button id="button1">Test Button</button>
</a>
```

you need to wrap your button inside the #label !
this is how its work !

Comment: It's a *bad practice* to use <button> inside <a>. It is not semantically.

Answer (score 0):

Put #label in front, and use `+` select next slibing dom

```css
#button1 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 10%;
  left: 15%;
}
#label {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -10;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
#label span {
  color: white;
}
#label:hover {
  background-color: black;
}
#button1:hover + #label {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<button id="button1">Test Button</button>
<a id="label"><span>Hidden Until Hover</span></a>
```